# List the properties of a .prototype?

Tags: javascript

With javascript is it possible to `console.log` or list the `.prototype` properties associated with an object of a given type?

I'm using a *firebase cloud-firestore* and would like to see what exists on the prototype for calls to the database.

For example a db call returns an Object of type `QuerySnapshot { ... }`. I'd like to see what exists on `QuerySnapshot.prototype`.

I can map through the returned values using `.map`, but if I console log out the object, it's not an array, so presumably it is inheriting a custom .map from prototype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get an object's prototype, [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get its properties that have string names, and [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) to get its properties that have Symbol names. You might want to repeat the process (going to the prototype's prototype and so on) to get the properties at every level.

The advantage to `getOwnPropertyXYZ` is that it includes properties that are non-enumerable, whereas `for-in` and `Object.keys` only return enumerable properties. (They also don't include Symbol-named properties.)

Alternately, you can `console.log` the object and explore its properties with the browser's interactive object explorer in the devtools.